# Error message: cannot find table 0

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, dataset

First I would like to apologise for the length of this post. But I want you to understand the entire issue.

I have to merge three datasets (`dsGetForm`, `dsmedication_details` and `dsbroadband_details`), and show the result in a table.

Sometimes `dsbroadband_details` contains rows and sometimes it doesn't.

This is what I am using right now to merge the datasets.

```
if (dsGetForm != null && dsmedication_details != null && dsbroadband_details != null)
{
   dsGetForm.Tables[0].Merge(dsmedication_details.Tables[0]);
   dsGetForm.Tables[0].Merge(dsbroadband_details.Tables[0]);
}
else if (dsGetForm == null && dsmedication_details != null)
{
   dsGetForm = dsmedication_details;
}
else if (dsGetForm == null && dsbroadband_details != null )
{
   dsGetForm = dsbroadband_details;
}
```

The problem is that, the stored procedure (SP) which is used to fill the dataset `dsbroadband_details` is giving me this error message when the result of stored procedure is null

> Error message: Cannot find table 0. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information 
>   about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail,
>   System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]:
>   Cannot find table 0

This is my stored procedure

```
Alter Procedure dbo.OEA_SP_GET_BROADBAND ( 
                @appid    NUMERIC,
                @clientid NUMERIC,
                @Lang Varchar(10))
AS 
   SET nocount  ON 
   BEGIN 
  declare @PIName as varchar(100)
  declare @username as varchar(20)
  declare @pform_id as varchar(20)
  declare @pform_desc as varchar(100)
  declare @userid varchar(20)
  declare @msn tinyint

  set @PIName=''
  if exists(SELECT app_id from ext_well_new_programs (nolock) where app_id=@appid and new_prog_id='BB' and status='A')
  begin
      select @PIName=dbo.oea_fn_fetch_fullname(@appid,primary_msn,1,@lang,@clientID) 
          from app_application with (nolock)
      where app_id = @appid
  end 

  if @PIName <> ''
  begin
    select Distinct @username = dbo.oea_fn_fetch_caaname(prog.last_update_id, 30000) 
            from app_prog_submission prog (nolock) 
            where app_id = @appid

            select @userid = user_id, @msn = primary_msn 
            from app_application (nolock) 
            where app_id = @appid

            set @pform_id = 'learnmore'
    set @pform_desc = 'Cash Back for Broadband at Home'

    select @PIName as mem_name, @appid as app_id, @username as username, @pform_id as pform_id, @pform_desc as pform_desc, 0 as noncust, @userid as userid, @msn as msn
 END
     End
```

I think, I need to add a `else` condition after `if @PIName <> ''` condition.

My question is what should that else condition be?

Since I only need the values of the select statement (at the end) of the `if @PIName <> ''`
condition when this condition is true, I am a bit confused what else that should be?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How do you Fill your DataSet? I think the problem is in your code, you need to check also this dsGetForm.Tables[0] != null or  dsGetForm.Tables.Count > 0 for each one of your datasets

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like there are cases when your SP doesn't return any results, therefore no "table 0". I would rather construct a @results memory table, insert data (if any) in this table and do a final `select mem_name, app_id, ... from @results` before exiting the SP. Or any other SQL construct that actually returns a resultset, even empty.